# getIntent().getStringExtra("name") returns null

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm currently making a "Battleships" game for my school project.
first off, i put Strings named "hostState" and "key" in the intent extra and start the activity:

```
public void startGame(String key){
    i = new Intent(OnlineGame.this, Start.class);
    i.putExtra("key", key);
    i.putExtra("hostState", hostState);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

when i try to retrieve the string, it returns null. this is how I attempted to retrieve the strings:

```
key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
isHost = getIntent().getStringExtra("hostState");
```

when I ran the code in debug mode, it showed me that the intent (i) did in fact contain the extras that i put in it, but for some reason it doesn't remember those when I attempt to get them through `getIntent().getStringExtra();`

i have checked that all of the names aligned, capital letters, etc. and that I was using the right format for sending and receiving the extra (I made a demo app to test the result and it came out perfectly as expected).

Comment: First check key and hostState have value or not. If have please try to print in your logcats.

Comment: inside of what lifecycle method are you calling `getIntent`?

Comment: what is  i.putExtra("key", key);  key value?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I have checked, they did have a value when i checked them... they seemed to have lost it when i tried to get them from ```getIntent().getStringExtra()```

Comment: @Blundell sorry for my lack of understanding.. do you mind clarifying?

Comment: @GaneshPokale it basically generated a random string (i.e "ik7d") and i want it to transfer to the next activity. when checking ```i.putExtra("key", key)```, the value of key is indeed the correct value i want to transfer

Comment: key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
isHost = getIntent().getStringExtra("hostState");

call these lines just after

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

and print them @AsafSanany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
key = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
isHost = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hostState");
```

or if its not working update putextra (Manual Typecast)

```
public void startGame(String key){
                i = new Intent(OnlineGame.this, Start.class);
                i.putExtra("key", ""+key);
                i.putExtra("hostState", ""+hostState);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: this Worked! can you please explain why when i just sent the strings it didn't work?

Comment: May be your putExtra put as Object instead String

Comment: @AsafSanany I know this is a very old answer, but for the others that find this like me, I was passing an `integer` and trying to pull it as a `string`, so you either have to change your value types to match or do something like `i.putExtra("key", String.valueOf(key));`

Answer (score 0):

call method like this **startGame("ABC", "XYZ");**

```
public void startGame(String key,String hostState){
                i = new Intent(OnlineGame.this, Start.class);
                i.putExtra("key", key);
                i.putExtra("hostState", hostState);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: you made `hostState` a method parameter. Why is that going to fix the issue?

Comment: you did not put any value in hotstate so might be you are getting a null pointer

Comment: `hostState` is clearly a class member, otherwise this would not compile. As such, it probably has a value. And not having a value does not cause an NPE.

Comment: on which place you called startGame() method??

Comment: the string ```hostState``` held the right value when put into i... care to explain how getting it as a method parameter would help?

Comment: @MayurPanchal i call it in the first activity (below onCreate())

Comment: first, you getting both values after you passed this value to the method.